# MongoDB - Add to new information to document inside array, inside a document, inside another array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Sorry if my title makes no sense. I'll gladly update it but I'm very new to MongoDB and I'm not sure how to ask. I've searched through many posts and documentation but I can't seem to figure this out. I'm trying to make the following change to a document. I am working in python using pymongo, but converting straight shell commands to python hasn't been an issue thus far.

```
 {'_id': ObjectId('633c6ee4317752423543e8c8'),
  'ID1': -1,
  'Engagements': [
                  {'ID2': '-2',
                   'Session': [
                             {'GUID': '123', 'Created_Date': '01-01-2022'},
                             {'GUID': '012', 'Created_Date': '01-01-2021'}
                               ]},
                  {'ID2': '-3',
                   'Session': [
                             {'GUID': '234', 'Created_Date': '01-02-2022'},
                             {'GUID': '456', 'Created_Date': '01-03-2022'}
                              ]}
                  ]
  }
```

I want to find where 'GUID' == '123' and insert information there. It would look like:

```
 {'_id': ObjectId('633c6ee4317752423543e8c8'),
  'ID1': -1,
  'Engagements': [
                  {'ID2': '-2',
                   'Session': [
                             {'GUID': '123', 'Created_Date': '01-01-2022', 'New_Info': '999'},
                             {'GUID': '012', 'Created_Date': '01-01-2021'}
                               ]},
                  {'ID2': '-3',
                   'Session': [
                             {'GUID': '234', 'Created_Date': '01-02-2022'},
                             {'GUID': '456', 'Created_Date': '01-03-2022'}
                              ]}
                  ]
  }
```

---

Converting the accepted answer to pymongo code:

```
collection_example.update_one({"_id": ObjectId("633c6ee4317752423543e8c8")},
{"$set": {"Engagements.$[engElem].Session.$[sessElem].newInfo": "Cool new stuff"}},
array_filters = [{"engElem.ID2": "-2"},{"sessElem.GUID": "123"}],
upsert = False)
```

Comment: Do you also know that `'ID2': '-2'` to help perform the update?

Comment: Yes, for each GUID I would also know the ID2 value.

Comment: "Update nested array" is what you're doing here. @rickhg12hs provides one of the options below (which is probably the simplest one). The alternative would be to use an aggregation pipeline in the `update()`. There should be other questions that describe this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using [`"arrayFilters"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("633c6ee4317752423543e8c8")
},
{
  "$set": {
    "Engagements.$[engElem].Session.$[sessElem].New_Info": "999"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {"engElem.ID2": "-2"},
    {"sessElem.GUID": "123"}
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0XfLcdEx3lo).